# Register-ScheduledJob for install appx

Tags: powershell, windows-10-mobile, appx

`Add-AppxPackage` add appx for the connected user at the tablet

`Add-AppxProvisionedPackage` do available the appx for the new user but not for the existing user

Moreover if I reinstall my appx the appx is not updated for the existing user

The solution is to create a scheduled task when the user logged at the tablet

```
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath C:\myApp\Test.ps1 `
                      -Name Install_AppxAtLogOn `
                      -MaxResultCount 30 `
                      -ScheduledJobOption (New-ScheduledJobOption –DoNotAllowDemandStart) `
                      -Trigger (New-JobTrigger -AtLogOn)
```

`test.ps1` verify if the appx exists and verify the version and reinstall but it doesn't work, it work only for the user which create the Scheduled Task

Do you have a another idea for my problem?

Comment: Have you tried running the Task as the 'System' account and running with highest privileges?

Comment: I tried with users groups and highest privileges, I saw the power shell but it doesn't work on a another user

Comment: Does the other user have administrator rights over the machine?

Comment: No the other user is a domain users.

Comment: That might be your problem, that the domain user doesn't have the rights to install appx/run the PowerShell. Have you tried login on as the domain user then manually running the PowerShell script? Do you get any errors or does it work?

Comment: No ... I'm going to try

Comment: sorry for the delay, the domain user execute good the script in the power shell but not in a scheduled task

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to create a schedule task with donaim user, I create this task with the interface scheduled task windows ans not by developpement code, it's more safe